# ARKit - Applying Force in User's Phone Direction

Tags: ios, arkit

I have the following code that creates a SCNBox and shoots it on the screen. This works but as soon as I turn the phone in any other direction then the force impulse does not get updated and it always shoots the box in the same old position.

Here is the code:

```
@objc func tapped(recognizer :UIGestureRecognizer) {

        guard let currentFrame = self.sceneView.session.currentFrame else {
            return
        }

        /
        let box = SCNBox(width: 0.2, height: 0.2, length: 0.2, chamferRadius: 0)

        let material = SCNMaterial()
        material.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
        material.lightingModel = .constant

        var translation = matrix_identity_float4x4
        translation.columns.3.z = -0.01

        let node = SCNNode()
        node.geometry = box
        node.geometry?.materials = [material]

        print(currentFrame.camera.transform)

        node.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, shape: nil)

        node.simdTransform = matrix_multiply(currentFrame.camera.transform, translation)
        node.physicsBody?.applyForce(SCNVector3(0,2,-10), asImpulse: true)

        self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)


    }
```

Line 26 is where I apply the force but it does not take into account the user's current phone orientation. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On line 26 you're passing a constant vector to `applyForce`. That method takes a vector in world space, so passing a constant vector means you're always applying a force in the same direction — if you want a direction that's based on the direction the camera or something else is pointing, you'll need to calculate a vector based on that direction.

The (new) SCNNode property [`worldFront`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/2867392-worldfront) might prove helpful here — it gives you the direction a node is pointing, automatically converted to world space, so it's useful with physics methods. (Though you might want to scale it.)

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm :) Have an awesome day!

Comment: Could you please add any sample code to understand it ?